# Why doesn't TypeScript recognize module augmentation for a Vue plugin?

Tags: typescript, vuejs2

I have a Vue project that I'm building to learn both Vue and TypeScript. The project has a chunk of static data that I've chosen to make available to components as a Vue plugin, adding a property to the Vue prototype.

```
import _Vue from 'vue';

export default function myPlugin(Vue: typeof _Vue): void {
  Vue.prototype.$myPlugin = { one: 1, two: 2 };
}
```

I followed the advice in a [post by Peter Kuhn](https://www.mistergoodcat.com/post/vuejs-plugins-with-typescript), defining the property type in a `test-plugin.d.ts` file.

```
import Vue from 'vue';

declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
    interface Vue {
        $myPlugin: object;
    }
}
```

Finally, I `import` and `use()` the plugin.

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import MyPlugin from './test-plugin';

Vue.use(MyPlugin);

new Vue({
  render: (h) => h(App),
}).$mount('#app');
```

However, when I reference the property in a single-file Vue component, both vscode and the TypeScript transpiler throw an error that the property doesn't exist.

```
<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue';

export default Vue.extend({
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  props: {
    msg: String,
  },
  data: {
    one: 0,
  },
  created(): void {
    this.one = this.$myPlugin.one;
  },
});
</script>
```

The error:

```text
ERROR in /Users/kccricket/Projects/what-the-heck/vue-plugin-test/src/components/HelloWorld.vue
43:21 Property '$myPlugin' does not exist on type 'CombinedVueInstance<Vue, { one: number; }, {}, {}, Readonly<{ msg: string; }>>'.
    41 |   },
    42 |   created(): void {
  > 43 |     this.one = this.$myPlugin.one;
       |                     ^
    44 |   },
    45 | });
    46 | </script>
```

Despite the error, `this.one === 1` as I'd expect once the code is built and executed. Can anyone pinpoint what I'm doing wrong, here?

I've posted the sample code to GitHub: https://github.com/kccricket/what-the-heck/tree/master/vue-plugin-test

## Environment

```
"dependencies": {
  "vue": "^2.5.16"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "^3.0.0-rc.5",
  "@vue/cli-service": "^3.0.0-rc.5",
  "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.16"
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you augment Vue typings for use with a plugin - as in `test-plugin.d.ts` - you need to import Vue first:

```
import Vue from 'vue'

declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
  interface Vue {
   $myPlugin: object 
  } 
}
```

Its explained [here in the docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html#Augmenting-Types-for-Use-with-Plugins).

**update**

I don't see mention of it your post, but if you haven't done so you also need a shim for single file components:

```
// sfc.d.ts
declare module '*.vue' {
  import Vue from 'vue'
  export default Vue
}
```

You can see this in the [TypeScript-Vue-Starter](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Vue-Starter/blob/master/src/vue-shims.d.ts) repository.

**update**

Disregard the above, I didn't notice the sample repo. I managed to resolve the type error, see the changes [here](https://github.com/digital-drifter/what-the-heck/tree/master/vue-plugin-test).

**answer**

As noted by **@kccricket**, the plugin's implementation and declaration files were named the same, thus causing the module in resolve incorrectly.

```
// original file names

test-plugin.ts
test-plugin.d.ts
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that omission. Unfortunately, it didn't resolve the error, but I have updated the question.

Comment: Probably missing a shim for single file components. Answer has been updated.

Comment: I got the type error resolved, there's a link in the answer to the repository for you to look at.

Comment: It turns out that the real root of my issue was that `test-plugin.d.ts` and `test-plugin.ts` have a very similar name and exist within the same directory. If I rename `test-plugin.d.ts` to anything else and restart vscode, the error disappears. Thanks for your help. Feel free to update your answer and I'll accept, or I can add my own answer.

Comment: As a side note, it appears that if you export the `MyPlugin` type as `default`, then vscode's intellisense believes the the type of `$myPlugin` is `default`.

Comment: As a side side note, I restarted vscode because it didn't initially pick up on the change.

Comment: Awesome glad you got sorted out. I figured it was the file naming causing problems with module resolution once I saw the application structure in your repo. The other changes were just out of habit, vue cli has me trained.

Answer (score 7):

what worked for me was to have the below declaration *inside* the .ts plugin file:

```
declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
  interface Vue {
    $myPlugin: object;
  }
}
```

i tried having the same thing in the .d.ts file as recommended in that article, but intellisense still couldn't see it properly in the component code.

Comment: Indeed I had to put this into my plugin's .ts file. It was not working with d.ts file. Thank you