# Vue typescript plugin

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I am writing a vue logger plugin

```
export default new (class NestLogger {
  public install(Vue: any) {
    Vue.prototype.$log = this;
  }

  error(text: string) {
      console.log(text)
  }
})();
```

in main.ts

```
import logger from "./plugins/logger";
Vue.use(logger);
```

But in components I cannot reference `this.$log` - why?

In Login.vue

```
this.$log.error("bla");
```

Error: `Property $log does not exist on type Login`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [augment the `vue` type definitions](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html#Augmenting-Types-for-Use-with-Plugins) in a `.d.ts` file to include the type definition for `$log`:

```js
// src/my-log-plugin.d.ts
import Vue from 'vue'

declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
  interface Vue {
    $log: {
      error: (message: string) => void
    }
  }
}

export {}
```

Comment: Yes that solution is correct however what worked for me was including the above code in my `log.ts` file instead of splitting it into a `.d.ts` file. Same as this guy https://stackoverflow.com/a/54656902/8518207

Comment: If you add a `.d.ts` file, make sure it's in the source path configured in `tsconfig.json` for `tsc` (and Intellisense) to find it. Putting it in `src/` works for Vue CLI projects.